# Java 17. Springboot and Junit5 SpringBootTest upgrade problem with Endpoint.class

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit5

Fairly new to this source base which I'm trying to port from Java 1.8 to 17.   This forced a move from Junit 4 to 5 since Powermock was broke by Java 16 and it doesn't appear anyone is planning to fix it.  I've successfully migrated a couple projects, but got stuck on this one which wasn't actually using Powermock.   Been fighting this one for a couple days now.

Looking back at my changes, I've done the following:

- Upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.6.3
- Installed org.openrewrite.java.testing.junit5.JUnit5BestPractices and ran mvn rewrite:run.  This excluded junit from a couple modules, added org.junit.jupiter and changed @Before to @BeforeEach in my test config parent class.
- I then manually changed @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestConfig {

    @MockBean
    protected AuditPublisherService auditPubSvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
    }
```

I'm now stuck on the following error which I haven't be able to find in numerous Google searches:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.britive.pab.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/Endpoint.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ...
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Hence this all comes down to the code trying to find org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/Endpoint.class which AFAICT doesn't exist anywhere.   I strongly suspect it's a mix up from an older dependency, but can't figure out which one.    Finally, the pom.xml if you're willing to take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.britive.pab</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>audit</name>
    <description>Audit service application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- exclude junit 4 -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.britive.pab.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>pab-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.britive.pab.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>pab-security</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For CSV Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For File Utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Springfox Swagger Specification -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.898</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>4.17.0</version>
              <configuration>
                 <activeRecipes>
                   <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.testing.junit5.JUnit5BestPractices</recipe>
                 </activeRecipes>
                 <pomCacheEnabled>false</pomCacheEnabled>
              </configuration>
              <dependencies>
                 <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                   <artifactId>rewrite-testing-frameworks</artifactId>
                   <version>1.17.0</version>
                 </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What Spring Boot version are you upgrading from? Spring Boot 2 [changed the API for implementing custom Actuator endpoints](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Migrating-a-custom-Actuator-endpoint-to-Spring-Boot-2).

Answer (score 0):

> I strongly suspect it's a mix up from an older dependency, but can't figure out which one.

This is an `@Endpoint` annotation that belongs to **spring boot actuator** project. So this is where you should start searching I believe.

In spring boot 2.6.3 it resides in `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation` package and for some reason your code tries to search for it in another package and indeed it doesn't exist there: [Source Code Link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/annotation/Endpoint.java)

Now why the different package? It looks like that the `@Endpoint` annotation used to be defined in spring boot 1.5.x in the package that originates the error:

[Link to the old spring boot source code (1.5x)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/Endpoint.java)

So I conclude that:

1. There might be a custom endpoint in the old format somewhere in your source code that has to be migrated. You should really check your code for that import/custom endpoint definition. One of the external dependencies in theory can also be "guilty".
2. There might be a clash of spring boot versions. For that run `mvn dependency:tree` and examine spring/spring boor related jars versions. You should only see stuff that belongs to springboot 2.6.3